# Send mail from homepage. What am I missing in my code?

Tags: php, html, html-email

I would like to be able to send mail from my homepage but it aint working as I want. i get a mail but it doesnt say from home. Just says Unknown. The thing I have this in two diffrent places. The other place I use other textareas and there I get everything in my mail and it works fine but this other place I am trying to work I only want them to add there email and then it should be sent with all info.

My code on my page:

```
<form id="subscribe" class="clearfix" method="post" action="get_mail.php">
    <div class="field alignleft">
       <input type="text" value="Enter your email" onclick="if(this.value=='Enter your email')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Enter your email';" />
     </div>
     <div class="search-btn">
        <input type="submit" value="" />
     </div>
</form>
```

Then I have this php script

```
<?php

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    $address= "xxxxx.xxxxx@outlook.com";
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    //-----------------------------------------------------

    $name = $_REQUEST["name"];
    $email = $_REQUEST["email"];
    $website = $_REQUEST["website"];
    $subject .= "You have an email from your web site (from $name)! \n\n";
    $message_content = strip_tags($_REQUEST["message"]);

    $headers = "From: $name <$email>\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $subject <$email>\n";

    $message = "--$mime_boundary\n\n";

    $message .= "You have an email from your web site: \n\n\n";
    $message .= "Name: $name \n\n";
    $message .= "Email: $email \n\n";
    $message .= "Website: $website \n\n";
    $message .= "Message: $message_content \n\n";

    $message .= "--$mime_boundary--\n\n";

    $mail_sent = mail($address, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo $mail_sent ? "Success, mail sent!" : "Mail failed";

?>
```

Comment: Can you show us the error that you're getting?

Comment: You don't really need the `$mime_boundary` lines unless you're sending multiple versions (ie, html and plaintext) of the message, or you have attachments. That's one thing to remove. Also, you should ensure you have a mail server setup for your mail process to use, or include connection details for Gmail or whatnot, for it to send through. `mail()` runs off the *underlying* server's mail sending capability.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. Try replacing "\n" in $headers with "\r\n".
2. As far as I know, some hosts (I think GoDaddy or Hostgator do this for example) will override the "from" value in sent emails and change it to the one you have with them. This means that if you don't explicitly have "from@domain.com" in your hosting account you won't be able to send emails from that address and it will be always overridden. You have to contact your host to check this. I suggest also checking the script on another server if possible.

Answer (score 2):

None of your form fields appear to have names - your code here:

```
$name = $_REQUEST["name"];
$email = $_REQUEST["email"];
$website = $_REQUEST["website"];
```

requires form fields with the names "name", "email", and "website". For example, your "email" field needs to look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="email" ... />
```

Comment: but in the first case I need all this fields but in the second I dont. Can I pre-write them in the code and only add the email adress they commit in my text field? What would that look like? If I use the code above and they enter a email adress I get a mail but it says it come from a unknown. I dont get even who it is from.

Comment: `website` and `name` aren't special header fields, so they must be somewhere inside the source of the page that works. Can you find fields with those names in the original page? If you want invisible fields, just put them in as `<input type="hidden" name="website" value="This site" ... />`.